# jqueryui autocomplete stops firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am working off of the jqueryui autocomplete JSONP example here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Even in their own demo, I've managed to make this bug happen; unfortunately I can't *consistently* reproduce it.

If I start typing into the text box, it will autocomplete.
If I don't choose a result, and then "blur" the control (focus on something else), and then go back in to the control and start typing again, the autocomplete "source" function (sometimes) simply doesn't fire anymore, never again, until I refresh the page.
I have verified this by putting some logging code into the source function; the function just stops being called.
I can't identify the exact circumstance in which it happens.

Is this a known bug?  Something maybe being fixed in the next release?

*Edit: bolded the following statement because it's the meatiest part of the question, in response to someone downvoting the original:*
**Is there any way to "reset" the autocomplete object so that it starts working again in this case? I've tried running my $("#foo").autocomplete(...) again when the object loses focus, but that doesn't help.**

Thanks!

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  I'm curious if anyone else has run into this issue.

Comment: This is interesting. I can duplicate the error sometimes, other times not.

Comment: Hi, I have a problem like you, but I can consistently reproduce it. Go to http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ and type java then press the ESC key, SHIFT + HOME and retype java, nothing happens the second time!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$('input.autocomplete').live('focus',function(){

    $(this).autocomplete({
       ...your autocomplete options   
    });
});
```

if your source is a ajax call or method I would suggest saving your source value in a variable

Comment: I did try something like this.. almost exactly this. And it didn't reinitialize the control.  I might try, on focus, to remove the control from the DOM entirely and re-add it, but that seems like a rough solution.

Comment: ..and like I said, it is inconsistent and I'm not sure exactly how the planets are aligned when it happens. :(  The current state of things is good enough for a proof-of-concept, but not good enough for production code.